# Which version of gtk is compatible with Ubuntu ARM

Tags: gtk, embedded-system, arm

I am learning GTK+ 3 on my pc which has Ubuntu 13.10 installed. Classes such as `ListBox` and  `Stack` seem to be unavailable  for 13.10 as they are packed in GTK 3.10 which only comes with 14.04. My aim is to run my own GTK based GUI application on a cubieboard(ARM based) which will have Ubuntu ARM installed on it.

I want to know which version of GTK is supported by supported by Ubuntu ARM so that I may avoid having to re-write applications in a different version(not to mention going through the tutorials of that version as well).